# Assigning subnet IPs to OpenVPN clients in AWS

Tags: openvpn, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

I have a working OpenVPN server installed on the EC2 instance inside my VPC. It's used to allow remote users to access services inside private subnet. It's been a sufficient solution so far but currently all clients are seen as a VPN server IP.

Is it possible to configure OpenVPN server on EC2 instance and assign IP addresses (preferably static per user) to clients?

Let's say I have a `10.0.0.0/16` VPC with `10.0.10.0/24` subnet A, `10.0.11.0/24` subnet B. I'd like to assign IP addresses from subnet 2 to VPN clients.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using the NATed option (default), meaning that all clients will be seen as the OpenVPN server itself.

You could use the other option which is Routed. In this case, your clients will be assigned IP addresses from a range you define (10.0.11.0/24 from your example). Please make sure this subnet (10.0.11.0/24) doesn't exist on your VPC or OMLY your OpenVPN server is sitting in this subnet.

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that your instances in the private subnet, that your users are accessing, need to know how to reach the IP addresses of your users (10.0.11.0/24 in this case) because AWS doesn't know where to route the traffic that is destined to this "new" subnet, hence will be discarded.

The fix for this is:

- Add a route to your AWS routing table (on your private subnet) to send all traffic that is destined to 10.0.11.0/24 to your OpenVPN server.
- Disable Source/Destination check on your OpenVPN server instance
- Make sure the Security Group of your OpenVPN server instance allows traffic from 10.0.11.0/24
- If you are using NACL, make sure you are not blocking this traffic as well.